# You cannot define a correlation name 'links' more than once

Tags: magento2

Hello and thank you in advanced.

I have an error in product page of Magento 2.3:
You cannot define a correlation name 'links' more than once

trace:

> {"0":"You cannot define a correlation name 'links' more than
>   once","1":"#0
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Select.php(298):
>   Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'links.linked_pr...',
>   Array, NULL)\n#1
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php(357):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Select->_join('inner join', Array,
>   'links.linked_pr...', Array, NULL)\n#2
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php(336):
>   Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'links.linked_pr...', Array,
>   NULL)\n#3
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Link/Product/Collection.php(230):
>   Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'links.linked_pr...', Array)\n#4
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Link/Product/Collection.php(184):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection->_joinLinks()\n#5
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(917):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection->_beforeLoad()\n#6
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php(790):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->load(false,
>   false)\n#7
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->load(false,
>   false)\n#8
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection\Interceptor->___callParent('load',
>   Array)\n#9
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()\n#10
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Link/Product/Collection/Interceptor.php(390):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load',
>   Array, Array)\n#11
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(832):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection\Interceptor->load()\n#12
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Link/Product/Collection/Interceptor.php(1961):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()\n#13
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related.php(137):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection\Interceptor->getIterator()\n#14
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related/Interceptor.php(37):
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related->getIdentities()\n#15
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Layout/LayoutPlugin.php(71):
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor->getIdentities()\n#16
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), '\n    Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()\n#18
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput',
>   Array, Array)\n#19
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()\n#20
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#21
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#22
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult',
>   Array)\n#23
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#24
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult',
>   Array, Array)\n#25
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#26
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#27
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#28
>   /home/buybionette/public_html/index.php(40):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#29
>   {main}","url":"/bionette.html","script_name":"/index.php"}

This is a very basic site, no special modules or themes.

Thank you, Eran

Comment: I am also getting same problem.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix?

Answer (score 2):

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-3-Inventory-stock-1-doesn-t-Exist-On-Magento-2-3/td-p/120679

By PankajS_Magento

Here is the command to run in DB SQL make sure to update dbname.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY 
INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS
select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id`   AS `product_id`,
                `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id`   AS `website_id`,
                `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id`     AS `stock_id`,
                `legacy_stock_status`.`qty`          AS `quantity`,
                `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
                `product`.`sku`                      AS `sku`
from (`dbname`.`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
       join `dbname`.`catalog_product_entity` `product`
            on ((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));
```